# Swt LAyout: to able to layout the ocntrol

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am pretty new to SWT Layout. I have created a new composite with composite divided into 2 columns. Now I wanted to put 2 buttons in first column itself sd-by-side. is tat possible?

Thanks, tor

Comment: look here: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Add another composite as the child of the first column and set its layout to something that will arrange the buttons the way you want. Then add the buttons as children of that second composite.

Nesting composites and layouts is a key to building interesting layouts, whether in SWT or AWT.